# How to use reflection to get properties of a base class before properties of the derived class

Tags: c#, reflection, radix, propertyinfo

```
public class BaseDto
{
    public int ID{ get; set; }
}
public class Client: BaseDto
{
     public string Surname { get; set; }
     public string FirstName{ get; set; }
     public string email{ get; set; }    
}

PropertyInfo[] props = typeof(Client).GetProperties();
```

> This will list the properties in this order:
>      Surname, FirstName, email, ID
>
> Want the properties to display in this order:
>      ID, Surname, FirstName, email

Answer (score 10):

Maybe this ?

```
// this is alternative for typeof(T).GetProperties()
// that returns base class properties before inherited class properties
protected PropertyInfo[] GetBasePropertiesFirst(Type type)
{
    var orderList = new List<Type>();
    var iteratingType = type;
    do
    {
        orderList.Insert(0, iteratingType);
        iteratingType = iteratingType.BaseType;
    } while (iteratingType != null);

    var props = type.GetProperties()
        .OrderBy(x => orderList.IndexOf(x.DeclaringType))
        .ToArray();

    return props;
}
```

Comment: I don't see any problem with this, I don't compare `DeclaringType` I get the index of it and compre the index. Try it out :)

Comment: but very ugly unfortunately

Comment: @Ozzy So how'll you do that elegantly?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if there is a quicker way to do it, but first, get the type of the base type that you inherit from.

```
    typeof(Client).BaseType
```

After that you can get only the base properties using bindingflags.

```
    BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly
```

After that do the same for the Client type, and append the result.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer linq based solution:

```
var baseProps = typeof(BaseDto).GetProperties();
var props = typeof(Client).GetProperties();

var allProps = baseProps
   .Concat(props.Where(p => baseProps
      .Select(b => b.Name)
      .Contains(p.Name) == false));
```

Comment: Note this won't work for multi level inheritance.. Needs more work and poor performing also..

Comment: @SriramSakthivel agree

Comment: Thanks. In my case I do use multi level inheritance.

Comment: @stig-red Ok, at this point you should use SriramSakthivel's code. It will work out for you.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
Dictionary<string, PropertyInfo> _PropertyIndex = new Dictionary<string, PropertyInfo>();

Type thisType = typeof(Client);

foreach (PropertyInfo pi in thisType.BaseType.GetProperties())
    _PropertyIndex.Add(pi.Name.ToUpper(), pi);
foreach (PropertyInfo pi in thisType.GetProperties())
    if( !_PropertyIndex.ContainsKey(pi.Name.ToUpper()))
        _PropertyIndex.Add(pi.Name.ToUpper(), pi);
```