# How to get static properties from base type via reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

I try to get static properties from a base type via reflection. There are many questions regarding this topic on this side, but they all focus on getting non static properties of a base type or static properties from the target type.

```
public class A
{
    public static string STATIC_BaseProp => "STATIC_BaseProp"; //<-- I want this
    public string BaseProp => "BaseProp";
}

public class B : A
{
    public static string STATIC_Prop => "STATIC_Prop";
    public string Prop => "PROP";
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var type = typeof(B);
    foreach (var propertyInfo in type.GetProperties())
    {
        Console.log(propertyInfo);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
System.String STATIC_Prop
System.String Prop
System.String BaseProp
```

This seems to only adress the static properties of the target type and the non static properties of the target type and the base type. But I want only the static property of the base type (`STATIC_BaseProp`)

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get only the static properties of the base type I would suggest to access the [Type.BaseType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.basetype?view=net-6.0) property (like described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19996065/5174469)) and use only `Public | Static` [Bindingflags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.bindingflags?view=net-6.0):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var type = typeof(B);
    foreach (var propertyInfo in type.BaseType.GetProperties( BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static ))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(propertyInfo);
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

disclaimer: this works only for one level of the inheritance hierarchy. You would need to dive through the basetypes if you want deeper insights.

Output:

> System.String STATIC_BaseProp

If you want all static properties throughout the entire inheritance hierarchy you can use this combination of BindingFalgs:

```
type.GetProperties( BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy)
```

Here is an example to demostrate that it works also if you add a parent class on top of `A`

```
public class ParentOfA
{
    public static string STATIC_ParentBaseProp => "STATIC_ParentBaseProp"; //<-- I want this
    public string ParentBaseProp => "BaseProp";
}

public class A : ParentOfA
{
    public static string STATIC_BaseProp => "STATIC_BaseProp"; //<-- I want this
    public string BaseProp => "BaseProp";
}

public class B : A
{
    public static string STATIC_Prop => "STATIC_Prop";
    public string Prop => "PROP";
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var type = typeof(B);
    foreach (var propertyInfo in type.GetProperties( 
                                      BindingFlags.Public |
                                      BindingFlags.Static |
                                      BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(propertyInfo);
    }


    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Output:

> System.String STATIC_Prop
> System.String STATIC_BaseProp
> System.String STATIC_ParentBaseProp

Comment: Thank you. I didn't thout of just getting the base type of my target type and use it to get the properties... I wonder why it is possible to get non static properties of the base type from my target type, but not the static ones (I can get static ones from my target type).

Comment: @Olli "why it is possible to get non static properties of the base type from my target type, but not the static ones" it is possible. Use: `type.GetProperties( BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy)` but the filtering down to **only** base type properties seems not be possible using the `BindingFlags` enum. Or at least I haven't figured out how ;-)

Comment: yeah in my case i need the properties of the target and the base type (I think my question didn't really reflect that). So i can use the combination of binding flags. Maybe you could add this to your answere for future visitors. Thanks!

Comment: @Olli ok cool, I included the information plus an example to my answer